# Import missing for android.bluetooth.BluetoothAvrcp

Tags: android, import, bluetooth

I am trying to use the class BluetoothAvrcp from the package android.bluetooth but the import fails. It can't seem to file the class.

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAvrcp;
```

Is there anything that I need to add before being able to use that one?

SDK 22.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that these classes requires to build the android rom from the source.

Follow the following link to build from the source.

https://source.android.com/source/index.html